# disable Past in a textfield in codename one

Tags: textfield, codenameone

how to disable  paste option from textfield in codename one ?

I tried this but nothing happing :

```
Display.getInstance().setProperty("blockCopyPaste", "true");
```

Comment: On which platform did you try this? This is only supported on iOS/Android text fields. Not on the simulator.